# How are the multiple source files (.cc) compiled? in which order?

Tags: tensorflow, linker

I am working on a project that represents a network simulation. In this network, the signal undergoes multiple processing stages, each one represented in the library as a .cc source code file (and a .h file aswell).
Now, Since the signal processing must follow an order (each layer (.cc file) does some operations on the signal and then delivers the signal to the next layer (another .cc file), I was wondering how is this order decided? where is it specified inside the library? should there be a file containing a main function calling all those .cc files?

Another question is, when a .cc file is compiled, are all the functions inside if it run sequencially? like starting from the first line going to the last. If now, how are the functions etc. run inside the .cc file? In which order, and how is it enstablished?

I apologize if this question might sound a little dumb, but I'm relatively new to this kind of programming, and I'm trying to figure out the logics behind it.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

`.cc` files are compiled in the order designated in the makefile.  The order of compilation does not matter - code from a given `.cc` file is only run when it is explicitly called from a function (a small caveat here is that global data initialization may involve running code, but in theory it shouldn't do anything other than initialize data).

The function that starts everything off is called `main`.  You will find `main` in one of your `.cc` files.  By debugging through `main()`, you can trace how everything is called.

Note that compilation does not run any of your code.  All it does is build an executable file which you can run as a standalone program later.  Running this program starts `main`.

It sounds like you are coming from a scripting background.  It would be worth your time to read through a C++ beginner tutorial.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I wanted to ask you few more things: from what I understood, the main function is the one who starts everything. Then, like a domino effect, a function will call another and the whole thing happens. the question is: is it possible to have a library of .cc files, and no main function at all? or is it mandatory to start the execution?

Comment: You can have a library of code that has no `main`.  That would end up being linked with a program that does have a `main`, supplying additional functionality to the program.  The library couldn't run or do anything by itself.  For example, libc is such a library.

Comment: You were extremely useful. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> in which order [are multiple source files compiled]?

In any order. The order is not specified by the language at all. There are different choices between compilers.

Compilation of one translation unit does not depend on another, so language implementation can choose any order they wish. Quite often, translation units are compiled in parallel to utilise multi-core CPU's.

> Now, Since the signal processing must follow an order

A compiler doesn't do signal processing. It compiles source code into object files.

> Another question is, when a .cc file is compiled, are all the functions inside if it run sequencially

Functions aren't "run" by a compiler (ignoring compile time functions for simplicity). They are compiled.

Once you have compiled and linked a program into an executable binary, you can run that program. `main` function will be called first (ignoring dynamic initialisation of objects in static storage for simplicity) and you can call other functions from `main`.